# Jenkins - how to make job continue triggering build with failures

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkin. I have a master job that triggers multiple builds. But when one of the build fails, the master job fails and stop. How do I configure it so that the master job will trigger the next build regardless of the status of the current build.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is to use MultiJob plugin.

It divides the build into phases, where all phases can run simultaneously and independently.

```
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin
```